# How to measure the goodness of fit for a multivariable nonlinear math model

Tags: mathematical-statistics, goodness-of-fit

How measure the goodness of fit of my model?
c1, k1...kn, a1, o1,o2,o3 are the coefficients, while t and x1...xn are the parameters. I may change the model though.

[image]

Comment: Are these observable values? In that case, I would try leave-one-out mean squared error.

Comment: Good solutions consider the conditional distributions of the responses.  What can you tell us about that?  Really great solutions also account for the objectives you have for the model as well as what alternative models might be plausible.  Your thoughts?  BTW, what distinction are you making between "coefficient" and "parameter"? In many statistical applications whose would be considered synonyms.  Maybe the $x_i$ and $t$ are your *observations* (along with some kind of response, we must presume)?